# How can I add a second defaultFolderType to my xsl stylesheet?

Tags: xml, xslt, stylesheet

Is this the correct way to add a second `defaultFolderType`? I just added my second `defaultFolderType` in the same Bracket. I hope this is right. Can someone help me?

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Extent schema="TopEase 70A" docversion="1.0" partial="true">
            <xsl:for-each select="csv/line">        
                **<Folder defaultFolderType="Influence" defaultFolderType="Resource">**
                    <contains>
                     <Resource>
                     <xsl:attribute name="IDENTIFIER">
                     <xsl:value-of select="Identifier"/>                     
                     </xsl:attribute>                    
                     <name>
                     <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>              
                     </name>

                    <hasAdditionalValue>    
                    <reference type="AdditionalValue">                  
                    <xsl:attribute name="FIND">rootOwner/SettingsFolder/AdditionalValueSetting[identifier='_FV']/AdditionalValue[name='<xsl:value-of select="Financial_Losses"/>']</xsl:attribute>
                    </reference>                    
                    </hasAdditionalValue>

                    <hasAdditionalValue>    
                    <reference type="AdditionalValue">                  
                    <xsl:attribute name="FIND">rootOwner/SettingsFolder/AdditionalValueSetting[identifier='_SA']/AdditionalValue[name='<xsl:value-of select="Sanctions"/>']</xsl:attribute>
                    </reference>                    
                    </hasAdditionalValue>                    
                     </Resource>
                    </contains>
                </Folder>               
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Extent>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You really need to say why you are trying do this, because you can't have duplicate attribute names on an element. You could either make them child elements, or maybe do `defaultFolderType="Resource1,Resource2"` for example. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the sample you provide is incorrect.  Attribute names need to be unique within an element.    Are you trying to create XML that associates (possibly) more than one default with a given folder element?

Comment: Yes, so I can have two defaultFolderType. One which is Influence and the other one Resource